# Format tracing-rs log message with JSON in Subscriber/Layer

Tags: logging, rust, formatting, trace, rust-tracing

I'm using the [tracing-rs](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/) crate for logging in my Rust application. Currently log messages are just printed to the console but I want them to be appended to a log file conditionally depending on the [span](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/span/index.html). Some of the log messages are related to an ongoing process (called a `swap`) which has an id (called `swap_id`). If a log message has such as id attached to it via a span with an attribute `swap_id`, it should be appended to log file that has the `swap_id` in its filename **and formatted in JSON** just like the [internal JSON formatter](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/fmt/format/struct.Json.html) does it.

How can I correctly format the log messages in my Subscriber/Layer using JSON? Ideally I would somehow use the internal JSON formatter instead of implementing my own logic for all that.

This is my current code. It correctly appends some of the metadata of each log message that has a `swap_id` to the corresponding file. But I can't figure out how to format the log messages correctly.

```rust
use anyhow::Result;
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io::Write;
use std::option::Option::Some;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use tracing::field::Field;
use tracing::span::Attributes;
use tracing::{Id, Level, Subscriber};
use tracing_subscriber::fmt::format::{Format, Json, JsonFields};
use tracing_subscriber::fmt::time::UtcTime;
use tracing_subscriber::layer::{Context, SubscriberExt};
use tracing_subscriber::util::SubscriberInitExt;
use tracing_subscriber::{EnvFilter, FmtSubscriber, Layer, Registry};
use tracing_subscriber::fmt::{format, FormatEvent, MakeWriter};

struct SwapIdVisitor {
    swap_id: Option<String>,
}

pub struct FileLayer {
    dir: PathBuf,
}

impl FileLayer {
    pub fn new(dir: impl AsRef<Path>) -> Self {
        Self {
            dir: dir.as_ref().to_path_buf(),
        }
    }

    fn get_log_path(&self, swap_id: &str) -> PathBuf {
        self.dir.join(format!("swap-{}.log", swap_id))
    }

    fn append_to_file(&self, swap_id: &str, message: &str) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        let path = self.get_log_path(swap_id);
        let mut file = OpenOptions::new().append(true).create(true).open(path)?;
        file.write_all(message.as_bytes())
    }
}


impl<S> Layer<S> for FileLayer
    where
        S: Subscriber + for<'a> tracing_subscriber::registry::LookupSpan<'a>,
{
    fn on_new_span(&self, attrs: &Attributes<'_>, id: &Id, ctx: Context<'_, S>) {
        let mut visitor = SwapIdVisitor { swap_id: None };
        attrs.record(&mut visitor);

        if let Some(swap_id) = visitor.swap_id {
            if let Some(span) = ctx.span(id) {
                span.extensions_mut().insert(swap_id);
            }
        }
    }

    fn on_event(&self, event: &tracing::Event<'_>, ctx: tracing_subscriber::layer::Context<'_, S>) {
        if let Some(current_span_id) = ctx.current_span().id() {
            if let Some(span) = ctx.span(current_span_id) {
                if let Some(swap_id) = span.extensions().get::<String>() {
                    println!("swap_id: {}", swap_id);

                    // Here I need to figure out how to format the event in JSON just like the internal JSON formatter does
                    self.append_to_file(swap_id, &format!("{}\n", event.metadata().fields())).expect("Failed to write to file");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

impl tracing::field::Visit for SwapIdVisitor {
    fn record_debug(&mut self, field: &Field, value: &dyn Debug) {
        if field.name() == "swap_id" {
            self.swap_id = Some(format!("{:?}", value));
        }
    }
}

pub fn init(debug: bool, json: bool, dir: impl AsRef<Path>) -> Result<()> {
    let level = if debug { Level::DEBUG } else { Level::INFO };
    let is_terminal = atty::is(atty::Stream::Stderr);

    let file_layer = FileLayer::new(dir.as_ref());

    FmtSubscriber::builder()
        .with_env_filter(format!("swap={}", level))
        .with_writer(std::io::stderr)
        .with_ansi(is_terminal)
        .with_timer(UtcTime::rfc_3339())
        .with_target(false)
        .finish()
        .with(file_layer)
        .init();

    tracing::info!("Logging initialized to {}", dir.as_ref().display());
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can use the builtin JSON formatting, since they're tied to [`Writer`](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/fmt/format/struct.Writer.html) and it doesn't expose a public constructor.